# How to Trigger JQuery with AJAX Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I've seen some similar posts here, but unfortunately none of them have solved my problem.  My experience with JQuery is minimal, so I'm sure there's something I'm missing.  If someone could help me with this, I'd really appreciate it!

I created an ASP.NET/C# page that uses a JQuery/AJAX autocomplete function to display a list of tag or lot numbers the user can select from as they type values in a textbox (txtLookup).

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#txtLookup").on("keyup",function () {

            var textCheck = $("#txtLookup").val();
            
            if ($("#txtLookupType").val() == "tagNo") 
            {
                $(".autosuggest").autocomplete(
                    {
                        source: function (request, response) {
                            $.ajax(
                                {
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "Inventory.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                                    data: '{"lookup":' + textCheck + '}',
                                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    success: function (data) { response(data.d); },
                                });
                        }
                        , minLength: 2, 
                    });
            }
            else if ($("#txtLookupType").val() == "lotNo") 
            {
                var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ lookup: textCheck + '%' });

                $(".autosuggest").autocomplete(
                    {
                        source: function (request, response) {
                            $.ajax(
                                {
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "Inventory.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData3",
                                    data: jsonText,
                                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    success: function (data) { response(data.d); },
                                    //error: function (ts) { alert(ts.responseText); }
                                });
                        }
                        , minLength: 2,
                    });
            }
            else
            {
            }
        });
  });
```

The function works great when a keyboard is used to enter the values, but users can also enter numbers via an on-screen number pad I created (the program runs on a touchscreen).  When users click a number button, the number is written to the textbox via Javascript.  I'd like to trigger the autocomplete at this time, but I can't figure out how to do it.  Some of the things I've tried are commented in the code block below.  I've also tried modifying the function to use `$("[id$=txtLookup").keyup(function () {` instead of `$("#txtLookup").on("keyup",function () {`.  I've tried different events, like keydown, keypress, and change, but haven't had any luck. ​

This Javascript block runs when the user clicks the "1" button:

```
     if (object.id == "imgNum1")
     {
               var x;
               x = "1";   

               var textObj = document.getElementById('txtLookup');

               insertTextAtCursor(textObj, x);

               document.getElementById("txtLookup").focus();
               document.getElementById("txtLastClickedBtnValue").value = '';

               //Failed attempts... 
               //$("#txtLookup").trigger("keyup");
               //jQuery(document).ready(function(){});
               //$(".autosuggest").autocomplete("search");
               //$("input#txtLookup").autocomplete("search");
               //$("[id$=txtLookup]").autocomplete("search"); 
     }
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Edited to add the ASP.NET code:

Textbox:

```
  <asp:TextBox id="txtLookup" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="155px" CSSClass="labelAlignTop autosuggest" onfocus="javascript: setTextboxID(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

The setTetboxID function just writes the textbox name to a hidden field to store it to track the last clicked textbox.

Number button:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgNum1" ImageUrl="Images/InvNumPad/btn_1.png" runat="server" onmouseover="this.src='Images/InvNumPad/btn_1_Over.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Images/InvNumPad/btn_1.png'" CssClass="inv_btnNum1" onfocus="javascript: getButtonClicked(this)" onclientclick="return false;" Width="50px" Height="50px"/>
```

The getButtonClicked function contains the Javascript block I posted above that runs when the user clicks the "1" button and handles the caret positioning.

Comment: Can you please add the relevant HTML to the question. It sounds like you need to use `trigger()` and potentially the `input` event instead of `keyup`

Comment: Thanks, yes, I've added some additional code to clarify.  I'm not using HTML, I'm using an  ASP.NET textbox control and image buttons. I've also tried adding this to the block called when the number button is clicked: $("txtLookup").trigger("keyup");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much fiddly work, Divine intervention blessed me with the solution to my question. I wanted to add an update in case someone in the future is tearing their hair out looking for the answer.  To trigger the autocomplete code I posted above, I needed to trigger two events: touchstart and input.

```
function triggerAC()
    {
        //Triggers txtLookup autocomplete after touchscreen event
        $("#txtLookup").trigger("touchstart");
        $("#txtLookup").trigger("input");
  
    }
```

I also added touchstart to the third line of the code block I originally posted, changing

```
$("#txtLookup").on("keyup",function () {
```

to

```
$("#txtLookup").on("keyup touchstart",function () {
```